# Oracle SQL Select a Variable and split it by semicolon

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I am currently trying to split the Value of a Variable to select.

```
Variable = 'test;test1;test2;test3'
```

I would like it to look like this when using Select:

```
test    test1    test2    test3
```

So the split values are in different column when selected.

Is there a function to do that or is it even possible to do something like this?

Comment: Okay, that is a big change. Not rows, but columns now. As a query always returns a pre-defined table, i.e. the columns and their types are known when writing the query, we must know how many columns to select. Can we assume it is always four columns? Why are you doing this anyway? What do you need this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you have semi-colon separated list of values. You said that you want to have them in different rows, but - that's not what example shows ... this:

```
I would like it to look like this when using Select:

test test1 test2 test3
```

is only one row, with space as a separator.

---

Anyway: presuming that you really want different rows, then replace current separator with a line feed character (chr(10)), e.g.

```
SQL> select replace('test;test1;test2;test3', ';', chr(10)) result
  2  from dual;

RESULT
----------------------
test
test1
test2
test3


SQL>
```

---

As it turns out you need different *columns* after all, then - with such a sample data - regular expressions are a simple solution:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'test;test1;test2;test3' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1) col1,
  4         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2) col2,
  5         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3) col3,
  6         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 4) col4
  7  from test;

COL1 COL2  COL3  COL4
---- ----- ----- -----
test test1 test2 test3

SQL>
```

Comment: what is the chr(10) for?

Comment: And i meant in different Column... not rows.. sry about the confusion

Comment: chr(10) is a line feed character (didn't you see it in text I already wrote? Read carefully). After you edited the question, it shows output as my code returns, but that's not "different column", that's just one column.

Comment: I edited it again like it was before except that it says column. is there a way to use say:
Select replace(variable, ';', chr(10)) result from dual; so i would use the variable name and if possible all in different column

Comment: So it is different columns; OK. In that case, regular expressions might help. See an example in edited answer.

Comment: This worked good inside an SQL Windows, but when using it inside a procedure it says "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement"

Comment: Yes, because - in PL/SQL - you have to "put" those values into something. So, create 4 local variables and select INTO them.